# Determining the resonant angular frequency

Tags: lcr

[image]

I am facing trouble with finding out the resonant angular frequency of the above circuit.I know that at resonance impedence of the circuit is minimum.I am new to this topic and I tried to find out the impedence of each branch and then to get the minimum,but I failed..

[image]

I tried differentiation after this but it is not giving the correct answer.
tAny way to solve such questions will be highly appreciated.Thanks.

Comment: What have you figured out so far? You have not shown any work. In what way did you 'fail'? If you calculate the total impedance you can differentiate that number wrt omega and equate to zero to find the minima or maxima.,

Comment: 1st branch needs review to correct

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 couldnot get you? Please explain me what is wrong with the first branch

Comment: Since a resonant circuit occurs where reactances are conjugates of each other where specifically the reactance cancels to find a min. or max impedance and the Q is the ratio of reactance to resistance for series and visa versa for parallel, so you cannot ignore phase and just examine the apparent impedance , so  \$Z(\omega )=(R+j\omega L) // (1 / j\omega C) \$  where 1/j=-j in other words keep impedance in complex form.

Comment: How is the resonance point defined? Min or max impedance? I don`t think so. It is the PHASE which matters: The phase of the impedance resp. admittance must be ZERO at f=fo. And this is not always identical with minimum or maximum of the magnitude.

Comment: From the definition of resonance it follows that you simply must set the imag. part of the impedance to ZERO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impedance of 2 parallel (//) branches is easier to add the inverse or admittance,Y

\$Z(\omega )=(R+j\omega L) // (1 / j\omega C) \$

or 
\$Y(\omega )=\frac{1}{ Z(\omega )}=\frac{1}{R+j\omega L} +  \frac{j\omega C}{1} \$

to find resonance, differentiate \$df(\omega )/d(\omega )=0\$

if \$Y(\omega) = \frac{1+j\omega C(R+j\omega L)}{R+j\omega L} \$, then \$Y'(\omega) =... \$

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But differentiation isn't giving the correct answer.It result into an expression containing both complex and real parameters from which 'w' cannot be determined.

Comment: Set the imag. part of the impedance to zero. This is identical to a zero phase shift and gives the correct resonant frequency.

Comment: you can do the same by setting the real part of Series R to 0 as well.